# Загрузка файлов на внешнее апи с помощью ktor

Tags: kotlin, telegram-bot, httpclient, ktor

Я пишу враппер для telegram bot api на `kotlin`, используя [ktor](https://ktor.io/) и наткнулся на проблему - я никак не могу понять как загружать файлы на tda.

Tba предоставляет 3 способа загрузка файлов (Выдержка из [документации](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sending-files)):

**There are three ways to send files (photos, stickers, audio, media, etc.):**

1. If the file is already stored somewhere on the Telegram servers, you don't need to reupload it: each file object has a file_id field, simply pass this file_id as a parameter instead of uploading. There are no limits for files sent this way.
2. Provide Telegram with an HTTP URL for the file to be sent. Telegram will download and send the file. 5 MB max size for photos and 20 MB max for other types of content.
3. Post the file using multipart/form-data in the usual way that files are uploaded via the browser. 10 MB max size for photos, 50 MB for other files.

С отправкой файлов по `URL` и `file_id` всё понятно и работает.

Сейчас у меня есть вот такая ужастная функция, делает запрос к tba и парсит ответ:

```
suspend fun <T> makeRequest(token: String, method: TelegramMethod, vararg params: Pair<String, Any?>, files: Map<String, String> = emptyMap()): T {
    try {
        val data: List<PartData> = formData {
            files.forEach { key, fileName ->
                append(key, Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(fileName)).asInput())
            }
        }
        val response = client.submitFormWithBinaryData<HttpResponse>(data) {
            this.method = HttpMethod.Post
            url {
                protocol = URLProtocol("https", 42)
                host = API_HOST
                encodedPath = API_PATH_PATTERN.format(token, method.methodName)
                params.forEach { (name, value) ->
                    if (value != null) this.parameters[name] = value as String
                }
            }
        }
        val result = response.receive<String>()
        return parseTelegramAnswer<T>(response, result)
    } catch (e: BadResponseStatusException) {
        throw checkTelegramError(e)
    }
}
```

Без файлов она работает, С файлами - нет. (вероятно я отправляю файлы как-то совсем не правильно).
Я тестировал на разных файлах, вот результат:

1. отправляя файлы весом от `17,9 KiB` и до `56,6 KiB` я получал от телеграмма ошибку `Bad Request: wrong URL host`
2. отправляя файлы весом от `75,6 KiB` и до `913,2 KiB` я получал ошибку `413 Request Entity Too`

** я использовал метод `sendDocument` и посылал фотографии*

Как правильно отправлять файлы с помощью `ktor`?

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Спасибо, @alexanderbarakin ! Поправил.

Answer (score 0):

В итоге я понял как правильно пользоваться `multipart/form-data`, вот исправленная функция:

```
internal suspend inline fun <reified T> makeRequest(token: String, method: TelegramMethod, vararg params: Pair<String, Any?>): T {
    try {
        val response = client.submitForm<HttpResponse> {
            this.method = HttpMethod.Post
            url {
                protocol = URLProtocol.HTTPS
                host = API_HOST
                encodedPath = API_PATH_PATTERN.format(token, method.methodName)
            }
            body = MultiPartFormDataContent(
                    formData {
                        params.forEach { (key, value) ->
                            when (value) {
                                null -> {}
                                is MultipartFile -> append(
                                        key,
                                        value.file.inputStream().asInput(),
                                        Headers.build {
                                            append(HttpHeaders.ContentType, value.mimeType)
                                            append(HttpHeaders.ContentDisposition, "filename=${value.filename}")
                                        }
                                )
                                is FileId -> append(key, value.fileId)
                                else -> append(key, value.toString())
                            }
                        }
                    }
            )
        }
        val result = response.receive<String>()
        val r = parseTelegramAnswer<T>(response, result)
        return r
    } catch (e: BadResponseStatusException) {
        val answer = mapper.readValue<TResult<T>>(e.response.content.readUTF8Line()!!)
        throw checkTelegramError(e.response.status, answer)
    }
}
```